# How can I get Python to work on int inputs, converting them to two decimal points?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal

This program is intended to do the following:

- Calculate the purchase price (including commission fee) of stocks purchased.
- Calculate the sale price (including commission fee) of stocks purchased.

I would like the numbers to be accurately calculated to two decimal places. The issue is that if the user does not include decimals during input then the program doesn't recognize the decimal places.

This is why I've added the "broker_purchase_commission / 100.00" line, thinking it would force calculations to two decimal places. However, this does not appear to work. Any help is appreciated.

```
shares_purchased = input("How many shares were bought? ")
share_initial_price = input("What was the price per share? $")
broker__purchase_commission = input("What percentage commission is due to the stockbroker? ")
broker__purchase_commission = broker__purchase_commission / 100.00
purchase_price = ((shares_purchased * share_initial_price) + ((shares_purchased * share_initial_price) * broker__purchase_commission))

print ""
print "You purchased stock worth $%d" %purchase_price
print "Two weeks later you decide to sell the stock."
print ""

shares_sold = input("How many shares are sold? ")
share_present_price = input("What is the price per share? $")
broker__sale_commission = input("What percentage commission is due to the stockbroker? ")
broker__sale_commission = broker__sale_commission / 100.00
sale_price = ((shares_sold * share_present_price) + ((shares_sold * share_present_price) * broker__purchase_commission))

print "You sold stock worth $%d" %sale_price
```

Comment: try this: "print "You sold stock worth $%.2f" % sale_price"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For money stuff, you need precision, you must use the decimal module and convert all your numbers to Decimal like:

```
from decimal import *
Decimal(number)
```

So you should cast all the input to Decimal like

```
shares_purchased = Decimal(input("How many shares were bought? ")).
```

and also cast `100.00` to Decimal in your division by using `Decimal(100.00)`.
For printing, make sure you do not cast the result to integer.

```
print "You purchased stock worth ", purchase_price
```

instead of

```
print "You purchased stock worth $%d" %purchase_price
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html for the doc of the module.

Comment: This solves my issue and calculates accurately to two decimal points. Thank you.

Comment: @lookininward, you comment is incomplete. the part after 'However' is missing

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use `float()` constructor? like

```
broker__sale_commission = float(broker__sale_commission)
```

Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), mentioning the number of decimal to print:

```
>>> x = 1.0/10
>>> x
0.1
>>> print '%.2f' % x
0.10
>>> print '%.3f' % x
0.100
```

So in your code, you code apply it this way:

```
print "You sold stock worth ${:.2f}".format(sale_price)
```